# How do I encode Manhattan distance in Mixed Integer Programming

Tags: linear-programming

Lets have two points, (x1, y1) and (x2,y2)

dx = |x1 - x2|

dy = |y1 - y2|

D_manhattan = dx + dy where dx,dy >= 0

I am a bit stuck with how to get x1 - x2 positive for |x1 - x2|, presumably I introduce a binary variable representing the polarity, but I am not allowed multiplying a polarity switch to x1 - x2 as they are all unknown variables and that would result in a quadratic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are minimizing an increasing function of `|x|` (or maximizing a decreasing function, of course),
you can always have the aboslute value of any quantity `x` in a lp as a variable `absx` such as:

```
absx >= x
absx >= -x
```

It works because the value `absx` will 'tend' to its lower bound, so it will either reach `x` or `-x`.

On the other hand, if you are minimizing a decreasing function of `|x|`, your problem is not convex and cannot be modelled as a `lp`.

For all those kind of questions, it would be much better to add a simplified version of your problem *with the objective*, as this it often usefull for all those modelling techniques.

**Edit**

What I meant is that there is *no* general solution to this kind of problem: you cannot in general represent an absolute value in a linear problem, although in practical cases it is often possible.

For example, consider the problem:

```
max y
  y <= | x |
  -1 <= x <= 2
  0 <= y
```

it is bounded and has an obvious solution (2, 2), but it *cannot* be modelled as a lp because the domain is not convex (it looks like the shape under a 'M' if you draw it).

Without your model, it is not possible to answer the question I'm afraid.

**Edit 2**

I am sorry, I did not read the question correctly. If you can use binary variables *and* if all your distances are bounded by some constant `M`, you can do something.

We use:

- a continuous variable `ax` to represent the absolute value of the quantity `x`
- a binary variable `sx` to represent the sign of `x` (`sx = 1` if `x >= 0`)

Those constraints are always verified if `x < 0`, and enforce `ax = x` otherwise:

```
 ax <= x + M * (1 - sx)
 ax >= x - M * (1 - sx)
```

Those constraints are always verified if `x >= 0`, and enforce `ax = -x` otherwise:

```
 ax <= -x + M * sx
 ax >= -x - M * sx
```

This is a variation of the "big M" method that is often used to linearize quadratic terms. Of course you need to have an upper bound of all the possible values of `x` (which, in your case, will be the value of your distance: this will typically be the case if your points are in some bounded area)

Comment: Actually the distance is just constrained and the cost function is on variables indirectly related. Thus whether its a min or a max is not really known.

Comment: In that case, you need to post your problem (or at least a simplified version) if it is possible: see my edit above.

Comment: Sorry about the mess! It is actually possible with binary variables if the distances are bounded, see the second edit ;)

Comment: Oh yeah that works. If x = -1 then sx is 0. Then we have:

The top pair of constraints becomes ax <= -1 + M, and ax>= -1 - M. Which is true

The bottom pair of constraints become ax <= 1 and ax >= 1 which is true and constricts ax to 1